# Secure transactions with Express & Stripe

Tags: express, security, stripe-payments, mean-stack, private-key

I'm trying to implement payments in my MEAN Stack application and I've seen that I need to provide my secret key as follows:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(private_key)
```

However, I feel like this is not secure enough. Which is the best way to improve the security of this code? I guess there are many alternatives, so every piece of advice is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider to put the value in an environment variable, and load it from here. Depends on the environment / backend stack you are using, you would have various way to configure environment variables.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try it out!